# layout_above,layout_below and layout_alignLeft don't work in relativelayout

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-relativelayout

I want to use XML to layout a view like that

[image]

It works on most devices but also useless on some devices.The dots shows well but the line was miss. If there are any problem with using layout_above, layout_below and layout_alignLeft to get the location of the line?

Here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32px"
            android:layout_marginTop="32px">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_date1"
                style="@style/style_text_result_date"
                android:text="06-20\n星期一"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_date2"
                style="@style/style_text_result_date"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_date1"
                android:text="06-15\n星期二"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_date3"
                style="@style/style_text_result_date"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_date2"
                android:text="06-16\n星期三"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv1"
                android:layout_width="20px"
                android:layout_height="20px"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/tv_date1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="56px"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_date1"
                android:src="@drawable/selector_icon_result"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv2"
                android:layout_width="20px"
                android:layout_height="20px"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/tv_date2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="56px"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_date1"
                android:src="@drawable/selector_icon_result"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv3"
                android:layout_width="20px"
                android:layout_height="20px"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/tv_date3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="56px"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_date1"
                android:src="@drawable/selector_icon_result"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tv_date1"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv_date1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="56px"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_desc1"
                    style="@style/style_text_result_right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tv_date2"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv_date2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="56px"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv2">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_desc2"
                    style="@style/style_text_result_right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tv_date3"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv_date3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="56px"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv3">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_desc3"
                    style="@style/style_text_result_right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/connect1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@id/iv2"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/iv1"
                android:layout_below="@id/iv1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9px"
                android:src="@drawable/shape_vertical_line"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/connect2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@id/iv3"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/iv1"
                android:layout_below="@id/iv2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9px"
                android:src="@drawable/shape_vertical_line"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use this, a better solution for your layout.
https://github.com/vipulasri/Timeline-View

Comment: Attach your style file for check the code @style/style_text_result_right

Comment: i solved this by customizing a view.